# ¿Como usar la clase Intent para mostrar las apps del usuario

Tags: android, android-intent

Quiero que mi app muestre las aplicaciones del usuario en un `ListView`.

He tratado de investigar y [me salio en ingles la mención a esta clase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695746/how-to-get-a-list-of-installed-android-applications-and-pick-one-to-run?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) el problema es que no salio como usarla para ese fin.

```
Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
List<ResolveInfo> pkgAppsList = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities( mainIntent, 0);
```

Si sabes por favor ayuda.

Answer (score 3):

Mediante un Intent definido como `CATEGORY_LAUNCHER`, puedes obtener un listado de los paquetes de aplicaciones instaladas :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
List listaPaquetesAppsInstaladas = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0)
```

Para agregar los datos en un `ListView`, este es un ejemplo completo:

```
    //Crea List para almacenar packagename de las aplicaciones.
    List<String> listaPaquetesAppsInstaladas = new ArrayList<>();
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

    //Obtiene datos de apps instaladas
    List<ResolveInfo> listAppsInstaladas = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
    for(ResolveInfo info : listAppsInstaladas) {
        // be added
        ApplicationInfo applicationInfo;
        if (info == null || (applicationInfo = info.activityInfo.applicationInfo) == null
                || !applicationInfo.enabled || listaPaquetesAppsInstaladas.contains(applicationInfo.packageName)) {
            continue;
        }
        listaPaquetesAppsInstaladas.add(applicationInfo.packageName);
    }

    //Instancía adapter con datos obtenidos
    final ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listaPaquetesAppsInstaladas);

    //Muestra datos en ListView
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Para obtener en un `ListView` los paquetes de aplicación.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]